Resolve Issue with VF Scanner with Security-VfUnescapeEl
I'm currently trying to go through the CodeAnalyzerGeneral and resolve all the security issues, and I'm running into some issues when trying to resolve the Avoid unescaped user controlled content in EL (rule: Security-VfUnescapeEl)  issues. I was able to resolve the Boolean, Number as well as Text issues with a combination of JSENCODE, IF, and TEXT. However, the output of the code I'm having an issue with returns a list that I repeat over.
How do I apply resolve the security to something like this?
<apex:repeat var="pv" value="{!(schemaInfo['Work_Order__c'].describe.fields.map[f.fieldPath].describe.picklistValues)}">

I'm not sure if this is considered a false positive, or if I'm doing something wrong.
